# How do you expand results of str_split in R while keeping an index in another column

Tags: r, string, list

I have string-based data that has been inconsistently divided (by an upstream process that I have no control of). It looks something like this, with some records split into separate lines and some not.

```
ID <- c(1, 1, 2, 3)
strings <- c("garbage", "trash" "trash \r\n garbage", "garbage \t\n trash \r junk")
test.frame <- data.frame(ID, strings)
```

I want it to look like this after I'm done with it:

| ID | strings |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | garbage |
| 1 | trash |
| 2 | trash |
| 2 | garbage |
| 3 | garbage |
| 3 | trash |
| 3 | junk |

I've tried using str_split to divide the strings column, but I don't understand how to flatten the resulting list back into a single vector without losing the association to the ID.

I could write some sort of gross for loop to deal with each line individually, but I'm not sure how to do this in R idiom.

Answer (score 3):

We could use

```
library(tidyr)
separate_longer_delim(test.frame, delim = regex("\\s+"), cols = strings)
```

-output

```
  ID strings
1  1 garbage
2  1   trash
3  2   trash
4  2 garbage
5  3 garbage
6  3   trash
7  3    junk
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(tidytext)
test.frame %>%
  unnest_tokens(strings, strings)

  ID strings
1  1 garbage
2  1   trash
3  2   trash
4  2 garbage
5  3 garbage
6  3   trash
7  3    junk

library(tidyr)
test.frame %>%
   separate_rows(strings)

# A tibble: 7 × 2
     ID strings
  <dbl> <chr>  
1     1 garbage
2     1 trash  
3     2 trash  
4     2 garbage
5     3 garbage
6     3 trash  
7     3 junk
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is using `unnest` after `strsplit`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

test.frame %>%
  mutate(strings = strsplit(strings, "[\r\n\t ]+")) %>%
  unnest(strings)
```

```
     ID strings
  <dbl> <chr>  
1     1 garbage
2     1 trash  
3     2 trash  
4     2 garbage
5     3 garbage
6     3 trash  
7     3 junk
```